# Find locations where connections are used Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, connection, connection-string

I have a raft of Excel 2013 workbooks that I have to refine, each with multiple sheets and multiple data connections and I am looking for a quick way to list:

- connection name
- connection string
- location(s) where connections are used (sheet name or range would be useful)

I can see all this information in the connections dialogs but am having trouble tracking them down programmatically. I want to do this one file at a time so am not worried about running code across all the files, just something I can drop in a module as I start work on the file concerned. So far I have found this on this site:

```
Dim conn As WorkbookConnection
For Each conn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
Debug.Print conn.Name
Next conn
```

but I can't find the location information to go alongside this. Any pointers would be very gratefully received.

Cheers

Kyle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Expected output :

```
(Connection's Name): Sheet'sName|1st Cell of Range
Connection's ODBC Command Text
(Connection's Name): Sheet'sName|1st Cell of 1st Range // Sheet'sName|1st Cell of 2nd Range
```

Here you go :

```
Private Sub List_Connections_Ranges()

Dim wC As WorkbookConnection
Dim rG As Range
Dim TpStr As String

For Each wC In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
    TpStr = "(" & wC.Name & ") found on : "
    For Each rG In wC.Ranges
        TpStr = TpStr & rG.Parent.Name & "|" & rG.Cells(1, 1).Address(0, 0) & " // "
    Next rG
    Debug.Print Left(TpStr, Len(TpStr) - 4)
    Debug.Print wC.ODBCConnection.CommandText
Next wC

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks R3uK , that's exactly what I needed. I couldn't see how to use the range object.

Comment: @KyleGorf : you are welcome! Just to see how this works, place a breakpoint in the loop, and right click on `wC`, and **add a spy**! Now you can browse it to see how the data inside is structured! ;)

Answer (score 3):

The code looks like ok to me. Can you try it like this to see whether you have connections at all:

```
Public Sub TestMePlease()

    Dim conn As WorkbookConnection

    If ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count > 0 Then
        For Each conn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
            Debug.Print conn.Name
        Next conn
    Else
        Debug.Print "No connection found"
    End If

End Sub
```

Edit:
More information about connection is in the library. To see it, press ctrl + space like this:

[image]

Concerning the sheet name, it is here:

```
    Debug.Print conn.Ranges.Item(1).Parent.Name
```

Concerning the connection string, Microsoft would not give you a possibility to access such information from VBA. If it is available it should be a giant security problem.

Comment: I think that you missed the point here : *location(s) where connections are used (sheet name or range would be useful)* The idea is to list the places in the workbook in which the connections are used